# Calculate the speed of hand gesture

Tags: image-processing, processing, kinect, motion-detection, simple-openni

anybody who know how to calculate the speed of hand gesture from hand tracking ?
(i'm using processing 1.5.1 with simpleopenNI 0.27)

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Speed is distance per unit time.  Therefore, speed is:

```
distance_between_hand_in_consecutive_frames/(seconds_per_frame)
```

To find distance in 3d, use [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) with the position of the hand in consecutive frames.

**EDIT:** A psuedocode example.

```
f1 = get_current_frame_hand_coordinates()
f0 = get_previous_frame_hand_coordinates()
```

Then you need a function to calculate distance.  Your input should be two tuples, here a and b, of size three, i.e. (x,y,z)

```
e_distance(a,b):
    d = square_root( (a[0]-b[0])^2 + (a[1]-b[1])^2 + (a[2]-b[2])^2 )
    return d

dist = e_distance(f0,f1)
```

Basically, here you just plug the tuple values into the equation.  I'm not sure how your code is laid out, this is designed for a *single* set of tuples.

Now that you have the distance, then we just need to calculate the speed.

```
speed = distance/seconds_per_frame
```

Wikipedia [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinect#Technology) that the framerate of a Kinect is between 9 and 30 Hz.  This means that your `seconds_per_frame` is between 1/9 and 1/30 of a second.

This will *only* give you the speed.  Your question asks about speed (which only has magnitude), but you can also get velocity (which has both magnitude and direction) fairly easily with a little trig.

Comment: thanks for your response. but my problem is about how to apply that method in  a code. could you show me an example ?

Comment: I'm not going to fully code it out but when I get to a computer I'll psuedocode it out and hopefully that should help you integrate it into your code.